# bash: No such file or directory error occurs when only I use 'sudo' operation

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I use Linux 18.04.4 LTS, and my kerner version is 4.15.0-162-generic.

My Linux server was infected by malware last night, so I run the vaccine program Clamscan and rebooted my server.
After rebooting, I can not use 'sudo' operation.

```
obiwan@my-server:$ sudo
-bash: /tmp/9CIBU: No such file or directory
obiwan@my-server:$ sudo ls
-bash: /tmp/9CIBU: No such file or directory
```

But I can run bash without 'sudo' well.

```
obiwan@my-server:~$ cd /tmp
obiwan@my-server:/tmp$ ls
pymp-sl3fdegr                                                            systemd-private-f5c049d24eb946789a05ab83dd7f7cbb-ntp.service-IGqIwU               v3init2.log  vtmpsmkDEpZ
systemd-private-f5c049d24eb946789a05ab83dd7f7cbb-apache2.service-svZsaz  systemd-private-f5c049d24eb946789a05ab83dd7f7cbb-systemd-resolved.service-KiPmpQ  vtmpsEsWit4
obiwan@my-server:/tmp$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS \n \l
```

I tried hard to find any similar cases, but I couldn't find them.

There are many cases where the bash is wrong or the password file of sudo is wrong, but the case where the bash error appears in the sudo command was not found.

I really have no idea why bash needs the */tmp/9CIBU* file.

If there is a way to fix it, please let me know.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Are you sure `sudo` runs `/usr/bin/sudo`? Hasn't the `sudo` executable been altered? Aren't there any additional sudo plugins installed?

Comment: Try running `type -a sudo` to see what the `sudo` command corresponds to. This does sound suspiciously like it's been replaced by some piece of malware (which has been partly removed, hence doesn't work "right" anymore). BTW, the general rule for servers that've been infected with malware is: erase (maybe after taking an image for forensic analysis) and rebuild it from scratch (or a backup from before the attack, that wasn't online at the time of the attack). You don't know what else might've been messed with. See [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231).

Comment: Given the input I think the malware edited your aliases. According to this:
`obiwan@my-server:$ sudo ls
-bash: /tmp/9CIBU: No such file or directory`
when you issue sudo command the shell is trying to execute `/tmp/9CIBU` which doesn't exist. So check your `.profile` or `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

Comment: Oh, thank you a lot! I find that my sudo is aliased with '/tmp/9CIBU'. 
Now, I can use sudo. Thank you a lot!! I hate malware...

Comment: If possible, make a fresh install. It's probably the faster and certainly the more secure way, as implied by the comments above.